# WCF Webservice and data corruption

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a `List<string>` of files that needs to be retrieved from a web service. The Retrieval method `RetrieveFileAsync(string fileName)` for a single file is called asynchronously. Since there can be corruption of file, the response from the webservice includes an MD5 checksum for that file. What is the best way I can fetch all the files from the service assuming corruptions occur. I'm thinking of maintaining a `Dictionary<string, bool>` that is marked if the checksum matches and repeatedly checking the dictionary items and issuing `RetrieveFileAsync` for all files that are unmarked, until all files in the dictionary are marked. Is that the right approach.

Comment: Are you afraid of data corruption at disk level even before you load it in memory in your WCF service or about corruption between wcf server service and client? In the second case, I think it depends on the channel/binding you use...

Comment: I am referring to the corruption between service and client.

Answer (score 0):

If you expecting data corruption between service and client you can try to switch on the Reliable Message Delivery. This should fix any corruption on messaging level:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
   <binding configurationName="myReliableBinding">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true" />
   </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

You can read more [here](http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,a6cb59e6-cbc2-4ce3-92b2-ea40bc5929f6.aspx).

Comment: But won't it force added security and make things slower?

Comment: This method will help you if you are using any binding except basicHttpBinding. There is no security requirements for this method. I think it will be not slower than trying manualy re-request corrupted files. Also your MD5 hash can be corrupted too during transmitting request :)